# Grails: Skip js from layout in particular gsp page

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a layout in which I have included a javascript which I would need throughout the application,
 Now I have only one gsp page in which I want to skip including this JS,
 Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Simple. Use a different layout on that single page.

Comment: well, that's good suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in my comment, the simplest and best solution here is to use a different layout for the single GSP page.